# How to return runtime of a given programm saved as an Integer?

Tags: java, arrays, runtime

I want that my method getRuntime to return the runtime of a job.

```
public int getRuntime(int job) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException
 {
  Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
  int[] i;
  i = getJobs();

  if(0 < job && job < i.length )
  {
   int realjob = i[job];
   return Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
  }
  else
  {
   throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
  }
 }
```

First of all I checked, if there is a Element in array jobs, with the index of the given job. Than want to return the runtime of this given job.

Problem: How to return the runtime of the given job, when .exec(command) wants a command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one Runtime in a java program, thats why its a static call Runtime.getRuntime(). What you want to do here makes no sense for me. Accessing the Runtime in java is used for executing commands in the operating system.
When you execute with Runtime you get a Process, perhaps this is what you really want.